# testbench simulation error: Length of expected is 32; length of actual is 4

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to compile my testbench at Modelsim, but it doesn't work and this error appears:

> ** Error: C:/Users/Ariane/Documents/faculdade/SD/comparador-4/tb_comparador.vhd(24): (vcom-1272) Length of expected is 32; length of actual is 4.

and my testbench code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity tb_comparador is
end tb_comparador;

architecture teste of tb_comparador is

component comparador is
port (    x, y     : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
AeqB, AgtB, AltB : out std_logic ) ;
end component;

signal A, B: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal AeqB, AgtB, AltB :  std_logic;

begin


instancia_comparador: comparador port map(x=>A,y=>B);
A <= x"0", x"3" after 20 ns, x"2" after 40 ns, x"4" after 60 ns;
B <= x"0", x"4" after 10 ns, x"3" after 30 ns, x"1" after 50 ns;

AeqB <= '1' when A = B else '0' ;
AgtB <= '1' when A > B else '0' ;
AltB <= '1' when A < B else '0' ;
end teste;
```

Answer (score 3):

The literals `x"0"`, `x"3"` etc. are 4 bits-wide, while `A` and `B` are 32-bit wide. VHDL does not automatically widen an `std_logic_vector`. You can use `x"00000003"` for 32-bit literals, or alternatively, if you're using VHDL2008, just `32x"3"`.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 Bit string literals "If the base specifier is O, UO, or SO (respectively X, UX, or SX), the expanded bit value is the string obtained by replacing each character of the simplified bit value by a sequence of three (respectively four) characters....".  "The length of a bit string literal is the length of its string literal value. If a bit string literal includes the integer immediately preceding the base specifier, the length of the bit string literal is the value of the integer. Otherwise, the length is the number of characters in the expanded bit value."

Comment: 14.7 Execution of a model, 14.7.3.4 Signal update "For a scalar signal S, both the driving and effective values shall belong to the subtype of the signal. For a composite signal R, an implicit subtype conversion is performed to the subtype of R; for each element of R, there shall be a matching element in both the driving and the effective value, and vice versa."